# Is HttpRuntime's requestLengthDiskThreshold in BYTES or KILOBYTES?

Tags: iis, web-config, httpruntime

The HttpRuntime's `maxRequestLength` property is clearly documented as *kilobytes*, and this matches expected behavior.

However the HttpRuntime's `requestLengthDiskThreshold` is documented as "BYTES", yet this does **not** match expectations or ~50% of other "online resources"; there appears much confusion..

The [HttpRuntimeSection.RequestLengthDiskThreshold documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestlengthdiskthreshold?view=netframework-4.8) says:

> The *number of bytes* that indicate the input-stream buffering threshold. The *default is 80 kilobytes*.

However, this documentation is at odds with the *default* IIS setting of "80" which would be *80 bytes* per the first sentence of the documentation; yet it cannot both be *80 bytes* and *80 kilobytes*, which is the claimed default size.

```cs
// Attribute from the documentation link above; can be verified in IIS Manager.
[System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty(
    "requestLengthDiskThreshold",
    DefaultValue=80)]
```

**What is the *actual* unit of `requestLengthDiskThreshold`, and where is it *well documented, and/or corrected, without any ambiguity*?**

PS. There appear to be many "corrections" thrown about in various comments that the unit is *bytes*, which is suspected to come from this questionable documentation instead of actual validation..

Other contradictory examples:

- https://dnndocs.ir/content/guides/tutorials/troubleshooting/ts-how-to-increase-max-upload-file-size/index.html - assumes *bytes*
- https://kb.globalscape.com/Knowledgebase/10526/Errors-or-performance-issues-when-sending-files-larger-than-10-MB - claims it is really *kilobytes*

> The "requestLengthDiskThreshold" value in Web.Config is stated in MSDN as being "bytes," but really it is "kilobytes."

Comment: If you believe the documentation on the microsoft site is incorrect, I'd suggest you provide feedback and get it changed. I don't see how you can expect that there'll be a *more official, entirely unambiguous site* that trumps Microsoft's own documentation. Yes, the documentation sometimes contains errors, because human beings.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The documentation *is* wrong. This question exists as there is no suitable unambiguous declaration of the units, nor any correction that is readily found online. Many people have provided the documentation link above as (an incorrect) claim. (While perhaps I, or someone else, could post feedback, although I wonder how these days, this has apparently not been a priority to address and has been erroneous for [*many* years](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/e1f13641(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)).

Comment: But again, what would satisfy you as **official**, unambiguous documentation that would trump the *official* Microsoft documentation? What you're asking for in bold cannot exist so long as the documentation itself remains uncorrected.

Comment: Perhaps some *other* documentation by Microsoft without the error (or at least without the ambiguity), a footnote in a usage example, an errata in a Microsoft-published book, a [semi-]official response from someone who worked on the IIS pipeline. Or even some reference source: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/Configuration/HttpRuntimeSection.cs

Comment: (In addition other hints that it is indeed *kilobytes*, the source has a comment saying: "requestLengthDiskThreshold="[KBytes]" - KBytes threshold to use disk for posted content temporary storage".)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I changed "official" to "well documented" to remove that restriction.

Comment: I have reported this problem to our asp.net group. I will tell you the exact result once hear from them.